# file_put_contents no funciona en mi servidor

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, canvas

Quiero implementar la firma electrónica a un proyecto que tengo, para eso estoy utilizando un signature pad. En local me funciona sin ningún problema, pero al empezar a hacer pruebas en el servidor, no me guarda la imagen en la carpeta que le digo ni en ninguna otra.

Por el log que me devuelve el ajax, entiendo que el error lo tengo al momento de guardar la imagen, porque los demás datos si me los genera y me los devuelve sin problema.

Este es mi index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Firma Electronica</title>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap Core Css -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Font Awesome Css -->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Bootstrap Select Css -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Custom Css -->
    <link href="css/app_style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
    <style>
        
        #btnSaveSign {
            color: #fff;
            background: #f99a0b;
            padding: 5px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-size: 20px;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
        #signArea{
            width:304px;
            margin: 15px auto;
        }
        .sign-container {
            width: 90%;
            margin: auto;
        }
        .sign-preview {
            width: 150px;
            height: 50px;
            border: solid 1px #CFCFCF;
            margin: 10px 5px;
        }
        .tag-ingo {
            font-family: cursive;
            font-size: 12px;
            text-align: left;
            font-style: oblique;
        }
        .center-text {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="all-content-wrapper">
        <section class="container">
            <div class="form-group custom-input-space has-feedback">
                <div class="page-heading">
                    <h3 class="post-title">Firma Electronica</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="page-body clearfix">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading">Firma</div>
                                <div class="panel-body center-text">
                                    <div id="signArea" >
                                        <h2 class="tag-ingo">Firme aqui por favor...</h2>
                                        <div class="sig sigWrapper" style="height:auto;">
                                            <div class="typed"></div>
                                            <canvas class="sign-pad" id="sign-pad" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <button id="btnSaveSign">Gurdar Firma</button>
                                    <div class="sign-container">
                                        <?php
                                            $image_list = glob("./doc_signs/*.png");
                                            foreach($image_list as $image){
                                        ?>
                                                <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" class="sign-preview" />
                                        <?php
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Jquery Core Js -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core Js -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Select Js -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
    <link href="./css/jquery.signaturepad.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="./js/numeric-1.2.6.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="./js/bezier.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jquery.signaturepad.js"></script> 
    
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/json2.min.js"></script>
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e){
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#signArea').signaturePad({drawOnly:true, drawBezierCurves:true, lineTop:90});
            });
            
            $("#btnSaveSign").click(function(e){
                html2canvas([document.getElementById('sign-pad')], {
                    onrendered: function (canvas) {
                        var canvas_img_data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                        var img_data = canvas_img_data.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
                        //ajax call to save image inside folder
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'save_sign.php',
                            data: { img_data:img_data },
                            type: 'post',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (response) {
                            //window.location.reload();
                            console.log(response);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este es mi save_sign.php:

```
<?php 
    $result = array();
    $imagedata = base64_decode($_POST['img_data']);
    $filename = md5(date("dmYhisA"));
    //Location to where you want to created sign image
    $file_name = './doc_signs/'.$filename.'.png';
    file_put_contents($file_name,$imagedata);
    $result['status'] = 1;
    $result['file_name'] = $file_name;
    echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Y esta es la imagen de lo que me devuelve el response del ajax:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Verifica que el directorio `doc_signs` existe y tiene permisos de escritura.

Comment: Hola! @Triby, si existe y en la desesperación para que funcionara le puse permisos 777 y tampoco guarda la imagen.